# Spring OAuth2 token jdbc auto throw Unauthorized when access oauth/token

Tags: spring, kotlin, oauth, oauth-2.0

I using spring boot, spring security oauth2 store token jdbc. But i have problem when i access oauth/token . It always throw me error :

```
 "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/oauth/token"
```

My project look like :

**WebSecurityConfig.class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class WebSecurityConfig : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {
    @Autowired
    private val dataSource: DataSource? = null
    @Value("\${security.signing-key}")
    private val signingKey: String? = null

    @Value("\${security.encoding-strength}")
    private val encodingStrength: Int? = null

    @Value("\${security.security-realm}")
    private val securityRealm: String? = null

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun authenticationManager(): AuthenticationManager {
        return super.authenticationManager()
    }

    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder(): BCryptPasswordEncoder {
        return BCryptPasswordEncoder()
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/signup").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .realmName(securityRealm)
    }


    @Bean
    fun tokenStore(): JdbcTokenStore {
        return JdbcTokenStore(dataSource)
    }

    @Bean
    fun accessTokenConverter(): JwtAccessTokenConverter {
        val converter = JwtAccessTokenConverter()
        converter.setSigningKey(signingKey!!)
        return converter
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary //Making this primary to avoid any accidental duplication with another token service instance of the same name
    fun tokenServices(): DefaultTokenServices {
        val defaultTokenServices = DefaultTokenServices()
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore())
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true)
        return defaultTokenServices
    }

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun authenticationManagerBean(): AuthenticationManager {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean()
    }

}
```

AuthorizationServerConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
class AuthorizationServerConfig : AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter() {

    @Value("\${security.jwt.client-id}")
    private val clientId: String? = null

    @Value("\${security.jwt.client-secret}")
    private val clientSecret: String? = null

    @Value("\${security.jwt.grant-type}")
    private val grantType: String? = null

    @Value("\${security.jwt.scope-read}")
    private val scopeRead: String? = null

    @Value("\${security.jwt.scope-write}")
    private val scopeWrite = "write"

    @Value("\${security.jwt.resource-ids}")
    private val resourceIds: String? = null

    @Autowired
    private val tokenStore: TokenStore? = null

    @Autowired
    private val accessTokenConverter: JwtAccessTokenConverter? = null

    @Autowired
    private val authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager? = null

    @Autowired
    private val passwordEncoder: PasswordEncoder? = null

    @Autowired
    private val dataSource: DataSource? = null

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(configurer: ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer) {
        configurer.jdbc(dataSource);
    }


    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(endpoints: AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer) {
        val enhancerChain = TokenEnhancerChain()
        enhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList<TokenEnhancer>(accessTokenConverter!!))
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter)
                .tokenEnhancer(enhancerChain)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
    }
```

UserDetailsService

```
@Service
class UserDetailsServiceImpl : UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    @Throws(UsernameNotFoundException::class)
    override fun loadUserByUsername(username: String): UserDetails {
        val user = userRepository.findByUsername(username).get()
                ?: throw UsernameNotFoundException("User '${username} not found")
        val authorities: List<GrantedAuthority> = user.roles!!.stream().map({ role -> SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.name) }).collect(Collectors.toList<GrantedAuthority>())
        return org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
                .withUsername(username)
                .password(user.password)
                .authorities(authorities)
                .accountExpired(false)
                .accountLocked(false)
                .credentialsExpired(false)
                .disabled(false)
                .build()
    }
}
```

UserRepository

```
interface UserRepository : JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    fun existsByUsername(@Param("username") username: String): Boolean

    fun findByUsername(@Param("username") username: String): Optional<User>

    fun findByEmail(@Param(value = "email") email: String): Optional<User>

    fun deleteByUsername(@Param("username") username: String)
}
```

Resource Service Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
class ResourceServerConfig : ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter() {
    @Autowired
    private val tokenServices: ResourceServerTokenServices? = null

    @Value("\${security.jwt.resource-ids}")
    private val resourceIds: String? = null

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(resources: ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer) {
        resources.resourceId(resourceIds).tokenServices(tokenServices)
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
                .requestMatchers()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**", "/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/springjwt/**").authenticated()
    }
}
```

Data Table User In Sql

[Data Table User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po5WR.png)

[Data Table oauth_client_details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyHTx.png)

Postman Request :

[Request access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OenST.png)

[Request authenication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnkRY.png)

When i request http://localhost:8989/oauth/token , it always throw me exception :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-11-18T18:15:51.084+0000",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/oauth/token"
}
```

I can't understand why. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding `configure` method in AuthorizationServerConfig.class, something like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
    oauthServer.passwordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder)
            .allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
}
```

This is java code, for kotlin it would be something like this:

```
override fun configure(oauthServer: AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer) {
        oauthServer.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                   .allowFormAuthenticationForClients()
}
```

I think you forgot to set the passwordEncoder in AuthorizationServerConfig class.

Also, try with `allowFormAuthenticationForClients()`. It enables authenticating the client using the form parameters instead of basic auth.

Finally, try with request like this [Request access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5bdJ.jpg)